# How can I use private docker image in github actions

Tags: docker, github-actions

I'm trying to set up a job in github-actions that runs a private docker image. I will do the build inside that docker image using the container option. [link](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer).

I'm using the following code:

```
jobs:
  container1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: saeed/privateimage:1
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: |
          echo "Runs inside a container"
```

But I can't provide my docker hub creds so it fails.

How can I authenticate to pull that private image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks like support for this has been added just today, see [blog post](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-09-24-github-actions-private-registry-support-for-job-and-service-containers/).

The post uses this example:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    container:
      image: octocat/ci-image:latest
      credentials:
        username: mona
        password: ${{ secrets.docker_hub_password }}
    services:
      db:
        image:  octocat/testdb:latest
        credentials:
          username: mona
          password: ${{ secrets.docker_hub_password }}
```

The documentation for `container` is [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer).

Comment: Yeah, noticed that as well. Legit.

Comment: A note that when the `actions-runner` is running inside a container the `container` feature is not supported (`Error: Container feature is not supported when runner is already running inside container.`). I have to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64035027/1423507) syntax still. Running self-hosted runners in Kubernetes.

Answer (score 34):

For those that are trying to use a ***custom*** Docker image published to the new GitHub Docker Container Registry at `ghcr.io` in one of your **jobs or steps**, this is what I did.

## Steps

1. Create a Personal Access Token, as seen on GitHub documentation for the [new Docker Container Registry](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/packages/getting-started-with-github-container-registry/migrating-to-github-container-registry-for-docker-images#authenticating-with-the-container-registry). To do this, go to your `GitHub Account > Settings > Developer Settings > Personal Access Tokens` and select the following options for your token:
    [image: Creating a New Personal Access Token]
2. Go to your project's GitHub repository and go to `Settings > Secrets > New Secret` and create a secret like this:
   [image: Adding a secret containing your personal access token to your repository]
3. Take that token and put it in your computer's environment like this (or just copy it, whichever works):

   ```bash
   export DOCKER_CONTAINER_REGISTRY_TOKEN=<the personal access token>
   ```
4. Push your Docker image to `ghcr.io/<YOUR_USERNAME>/<IMAGE_NAME>:<IMAGE_TAG>`. To do this, you can find so in the documentation for [Pushing Docker Images to the GitHub Docker Container Registry](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/packages/getting-started-with-github-container-registry/migrating-to-github-container-registry-for-docker-images#migrating-a-docker-image-using-the-docker-cli). In essence, you can do something in your computer in the lines of:

   ```bash
   # Login to your ghcr.io
   echo $DOCKER_CONTAINER_REGISTRY_TOKEN | docker login ghcr.io -u <YOUR_USERNAME> --password-stdin
   # As an example, here I pull an image, tag it, and push it.
   docker pull ubuntu:18.04
   docker tag ubuntu:18.04 ghcr.io/<YOUR_USERNAME>/my_special_ubuntu:latest
   docker push ghcr.io/<YOUR_USERNAME>/my_special_ubuntu:latest
   ```
5. Then, create an action under your `.github/workflows/` folder in your repository. In this example, let's name it `super-action`:

   ```bash
   # You can just create the file in whichever editor you use.
   # This can do the work though...
   cd $YOUR_PROJECT_PATH/.github/workflows
   touch super-action.yml
   ```
6. Open the `super-action.yml` action, and you can do something like this:

   ```yaml
   # Action name
   name: Super Action

   # Here, this action will be enabled on all pushes.
   # Modify this to fit your needs.
   on:
       push

   # Jobs section
   jobs:
       # The job that will use the container image you just pushed to ghcr.io
       super-job:
           runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
           container:
               image: ghcr.io/<YOUR_USERNAME>/<IMAGE_NAME>:<IMAGE_TAG>
               credentials:
                  username: <YOUR_USERNAME>
                  password: ${{  secrets.DOCKER_CONTAINER_REGISTRY_TOKEN }}
           steps:
               - name: super-step
                 shell: bash
                 run: |
                   # Whatever commands you want to run here using the container with your
                   # new Docker image at ghcr.io!
                   echo "--This is running in my custom Docker image--"
   ```

## Results

After you push something to the repo, you should see something like this running in your actions. In the following screenshots, I use my own docker image [found here](https://github.com/users/PabloAlexis611/packages/container/package/ubuntu-18.04-dotnet-sdk-3.1.402) and my own `super-action`.

[image: Docker image is pulled in the GitHub action]

And then, you can see your job's `run` commands being executed inside a container using that Docker image!
[image: Job executing commands inside the container that uses the Docker image at ghcr.io]

Comment: Something I have noticed is that if you happen to copy files in the github home folder (/github/home), they will be all cleared after the container has started.

Answer (score 8):

**Update**: check [@Benjamin W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64051330/1423507). GitHub Actions [added Private registry support for job and service containers](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-09-24-github-actions-private-registry-support-for-job-and-service-containers/).

---

The [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainerimage) indicate that the `jobs.<job_id>.container.image` should be a publicly available image:

> "The Docker image to use as the container to run the action. The value can be the Docker Hub image name or a public docker registry name."

You could configure credentials for accessing the private `docker` registry as [secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets) then use the secrets to login and run your private images for example:

```
  test:
    name: test
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: example.com docker registry login
        run: echo "${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}" | docker login example.com -u "${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}" --password-stdin

      - name: run backend tests using example.com/my-image
        run: |
          docker run --rm -i \
            -v ${PWD}:/workspace/source \
            -e PYTHONPATH=/workspace/source \
            -e DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="www.settings" \
            -w /workspace/source \
            --entrypoint tox \
            example.com/my-image
```