# Docker pull failed - Authentication required

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, docker-image

We are using GitHub actions to pull docker image:

```
  sometestjob:
    name: Some testing
    runs-on: [self-hosted, kubernetes, on-prem]
    services:
      db:
        image: artifactory.io/someimage
        ports:
          - 2010:9000
        options: --name some_test --health-cmd "ycqlsh --debug" --health-interval 5s --health-retries 10
    steps:
      - name:  step1
```

---

When running job `sometestjob`, error shows: `Error response from daemon: Head "https://artifactory.io/someimage/manifests/latest": unknown: Authentication is required`

To pull the image, username & password has to be provided

---

How to add credentials(username/password) to service `db`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use private docker image in github actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64033686/how-can-i-use-private-docker-image-in-github-actions)